# how to add into an existing column from another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, addition, missing-data

If I have a dataframe for example like this in R

```
id   val1   val2   val3
1     1      40     44
1     5      N/A    44
2     1      42     N/A
3     13     N/A    N/A
3     5      N/A    42
```

how do I add the values from `val3` to `val2` that are N/A so I can get a more complete data?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what technology are you using? This is too broad by the way.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (SO)! It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to solve your problem. I will also recommed to take a look at [the _how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It's also generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need to add the values of `val3` to `NA` values in `val2`. In this case,  you just need to take `val3` since if `val2` is missing, `val3 + val2 = val3` (with the `na.rm = TRUE` setting).

Consider the following example.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
                 val1 = c(1, 5, 1, 13, 5),
                 val2 = c(40, NA, 42, NA, NA),
                 val3 = c(44, 44, NA, NA, 42))

data$new.val2 <- ifelse(is.na(data$val2), # is val2 == NA?
                        data$val3, # if TRUE, take val3
                        data$val2) # if FALSE, take val2
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much :))